# How to allow custom uppercase tags in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, customization

Does anyone know how to allow having custom uppercase tags in TinyMCE?  It seems that TinyMCE doesn't like uppercase tags, even though they have been declared as valid.  Here is my TinyMCE config:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    language: "en",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,|,table,|,code",
    theme_advanced_path: false,
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    plugins: "fullscreen,paste,table",
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    relative_urls: false,
    width: "300",
    height: "300",
    theme_advanced_resizing_min_height : "10",
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : '',
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    valid_elements : "B/strong,I/em,SUP/sup,SUB/sub",
    extended_valid_elements: "CUSTOM"
})
```

Typing something like

```
<CUSTOM>this is a custom tag</CUSTOM>
```

doesn't work because <CUSTOM> gets stripped off.

If I change the init script to `extended_valid_elements: "custom"`, then it works fine - I can type

```
<custom>this is a custom tag</custom>
```

and the <custom gets preserved.

Doesn't anyone know any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: couldn't you just use lowercase tags?

Comment: No, this is legacy data, where all tags are custom and in uppercase.  Does this mean it is not possible with TinyMCE?

Comment: you could transform them to lowercases on editor initialization. i do not know about an other way (but there might be one)

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that?  I'd also be interested to know how to transform them back to uppercase, what event should I be using?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of how to do that (the reverse works analogue): http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-148450.html

You should use the tinymce onInit event and to change the tags back to Uppercase use onSubmit or onSave (alternatively you may change the content back before submitting your content on any other suitable location of code).
To add this handlers use the [tinymce setup configuration parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup)

```
setup : function(ed) {

    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
        $(ed.getBody()).find('p').addClass('headline');

        // get content from editor source html element
        var content = $(ed.id).html();

        // tagname to lowercase
        content = content.replace(/< *\/?(\w+)/g,function(w){return w.toLowerCase()});

        ed.setContent(content);
    });

    ed.onSubmit.add(function(ed, evt) {
        $(ed.getBody()).find('p').addClass('headline');

        // get content from edito
        var content = ed.getContent();

        // tagname to toUpperCase
        content = content.replace(/< *\/?(\w+)/g,function(w){return w.toUpperCase()});

        // write content to html source element (usually a textarea)
        $(ed.id).html(content );
    });
},
```